# Comparing Strings Containing Other Strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm comparing two tables to match their Address Line and Postal Code. However sometimes the Postal Code (USA) is in the format of 28272-0516, while in others just 28272. They should be matched correctly regardless of the trailing after the dash '-'.

In SQL Server 17 I'm using CharIndex to locate the dash '-' however run into a problem because not all Postal Code contains the dash.

Do you think I need some UNION to grab all Postal Codes in table a that does not contain dash, then ones that contain dash, then table b that contain dash, etc..

```
SELECT *
from a
inner join b
on 
AND a.addressline1 = b.addressline1
AND LTRIM(TRIM(LEFT(a.PostalCode,CHARINDEX('-',a.PostalCode)-1))) = LTRIM(TRIM(LEFT(b.VendorPostalCode,CHARINDEX('-',b.VendorPostalCode)-1)))
```

Comment: Why not simply  left(ZipCode,5) = left(OtherZipCode,5)

Comment: FYI - 2017 allows for trim(...) vs ltrim(rtrim(...))

Comment: Good idea let me give it a try, I'm overthinking it

Comment: Happens to us all  :)

Comment: Hi. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

There is an invalid syntax, try:

```
SELECT *
from a
inner join b on  a.addressline1 = b.addressline1
AND  case when  a.PostalCode,CHARINDEX('-', a.PostalCode) <>0  then 
   LTRIM(TRIM(LEFT(a.PostalCode,CHARINDEX('-', a.PostalCode)-1))) = 
     LTRIM(TRIM(LEFT(b.VendorPostalCode,CHARINDEX('-', b.VendorPostalCode)-1)))
   else  a.PostalCode = b.VendorPostalCode 
   END
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out I missed to remove the 'AND' but it still does not like the PostalCodes that do not have dash so it does not solve the problem.

Comment: answer  updated .. with a case for postacode without dash too